# large text renders blurry in Firefox but sharp in Chrome

Tags: css, firefox, fonts

I'm working on a very simple web app and want to display some text in a very large font size. When I open the page in Firefox, the text renders quite blurry or fuzzy at the edges, while in Chrome it is displayed crisp and sharp. The HTML/CSS to reproduce this is very simple, I was originally using a webfont but even switching to simple Arial I see the same: https://jsfiddle.net/2vwjpuc4/

Here's some screenshots:

[image: Screenshot 1]
[image: Screenshot 2]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>title</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="results">0.68</div>
</body>
</html>

#results {
    font-size: 800px;
    font-family: 'Arial';
}
```

I haven't done much front end development, so bear with me. I know there are a lot of similar questions, but I wasn't able to find anything exactly covering this situation for large text on Firefox. Normal sized text in Firefox on this computer looks fine, indistinguishable from Chrome. Btw this is a Windows 10 PC.

Is there a reliable way to render large text like this and have it look decent in Firefox? I'm open to any suggestions, I don't have many constraints on this project.

Thanks for any help or advice.

Comment: Seems to be an FF quirk. Though not really preferable, but how about using SVG text? This way you can at least tinker with its `text-rendering` attribute... sub-ideal, I know... (I tested FF against Edge)

Comment: Here's a quick comparison I created on [Codepen](https://codepen.io/renevanderlende/pen/VweOrRE?editors=1100). Worth turning this into a proper answer?? (Obviously open it in Firefox...)

Comment: Thanks for taking a look. that codepen looks the same to me, should it look differently? https://imgur.com/a/k4mP065

Comment: Try scrolling down, it shows your `<div>` and the SVG alternative below that. Open in FF and maximize your window. You wanted crisp large text, now you got it...

Comment: sorry I missed that, yes that works great and solves the problem. if you turn it into an answer I'll accept it. thanks

Comment: I'm sorry did I say something wrong? anyway, thanks for your help

Comment: A really weird bug on FF here. I noticed the bug doesn't appear on Safe Mode, and it starts to happen on 300px and larger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After testing several browsers (Chorm/Edge/Firefox) it seems that this is a Firefox specific problem (quirk? feature?) There is no proper workaround for your specific problem, `-webkit-font-smoothing, -moz-osx-font-smoothing, font-smooth` have no effect.

When at all possible you could try using `SVG text` in this case as SVG (probably) uses entirely different graphical routines and you can use the SVG `text-rendering` attribute to tailor the crispiness (somewhat) to your needs.

Here a snippet with a comparison of plain HTML versus SVG text (need SO **full-page** view):

```css
html, body, svg {
  height: 100%; font-family: 'Arial';
}

#results {
    font-size: 800px;
    font-family: 'Arial';
}
```

```html
<div id="results">0.68</div>

<svg viewBox="0 0 140 22" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <text y="12" text-rendering="geometricPrecision">0.68</text>
</svg>
```